# Организация файлов по методологии БЭМ

Tags: css, бэм

Интересует как правильно структурировать файлы в проекте, если я придерживаюсь методологии именования БЭМ (не весь стэк). Сейчас у меня следующая структура:

- base: layout, переменные, сетка
- components: переиспользуемые
  копоненты, например alert, button, dropdown и тд.

Вопрос. Что делать, если мне нужно сделать что-то уникальное только для одной страницы на моем сайте, например уникальный отступ, цвет и т.д., расширять компоненты через модификаторы?